# Redireccionar mediante los DNS una carpeta sin afectar su estructura

Tags: hosting, cpanel, dns

Ya se han visto varias soluciones para no le vemos factible a alguna de ellas, la idea es la siguiente:

tengo midominio.com/ecuador en el cual deseo que al entrar en esa carpeta me busque informacion desde otro servidor pero sin afectar la estructura url

Debido a que midominio.com/ecuador es un sitio en produccion la idea es no tocar nada importante que afecte a las demas estructuras de la pagina web

Probamos con añadir un subdominio ecuador.midominio.com y apuntar los DNS hacia el otro dominio y desde ese servidor poner lo necesario y es factible, pero no queremos perder lo principal que es escribir midominio.com/ecuador

Se probo enmascarar la direcicon url, es decir, desde midominio.com/ecuador crear un archivo que me muestre el otro servidor, pero no es factible ya que tambien la idea de esto es quitarle un peso de encima al servidor

Comment: Buen día, tu pregunta parece de el tipo basada en opiniones, lo cual no se apega a la estructura de el sitio, te recomiendo ver  [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Y por otro lado según los redireccionamientos que puedes realizar en los dns no creo que se a tan factible lo que ocupas, ya que lo que quieres es enviar  el trafico a otro lado, pero tu ya tienes un dominio establecido con el tipo AAA, que es el dominio de tu pagina, y el restante después de el dominio es solo redirección interna, donde no entran los dns, lo único factible que veo es lo que comentas de el subdominio.

Comment: Si exactamente eso es lo que se estaba pensando y pues bueno dejar un archivo dentro del actual mientras que se realizan los cambios